# FOREIGN KEY constraint help Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm reviewing mysql and I am working on composing foreign keys when creating tables. However when I create the foreign key I receive a syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (
    staff_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
    staff_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    staff_last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    staff_phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    staff_email_address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT staff_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (staff_id)
    CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
    REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_id)
);
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong here?

---

EDIT:

The error I receive reports as:

> 19:35:55 CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id), REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_id))  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id), REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_' at line 1    0.00025 sec

UPDATE: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.110 sec

How does one resolve error code 1215??

Comment: Can you share that syntax error to make life easier :)

Comment: 19:35:55 CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id), REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_id)) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id), REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_' at line 1 0.00025 sec

Comment: You are missing a comma after the first constraint.

Comment: typo error. voting to close

Answer (score 2):

You are missing comma:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (
    staff_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
    staff_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    staff_last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    staff_phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    staff_email_address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT staff_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (staff_id), -- here
    CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
    REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks but after I insert the missing comma I receive this error:


19:48:38 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (  staff_id INT(5) NOT NULL,  staff_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  staff_last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,  staff_phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  staff_email_address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT staff_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (staff_id),  CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)  REFERENCES computer_staff (staff_id)) 


Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.110 sec

Comment: @Ed_ make sure `computer_staff` table is already created/present in database before you add foreign keys which refers this table

Comment: Thanks Khalid, I think I need to use alter table after the creation of both tables, correct?

Comment: @Ed_ Yes this is correct first create your tables and then use `ALTER` to add constraints

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff (
staff_id INT(5) NOT NULL,
staff_first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
staff_last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
staff_phone_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
staff_email_address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Foregn_Key int,
CONSTRAINT staff_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (staff_id),
CONSTRAINT staff_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (Foregn_Key)
REFERENCES computer_staff (Foregn_Key)
);
```

Comment: Thanks isfaq but I am still getting Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.110 sec

Comment: you use staff_id as  primary key and same you use as a foriegn key so this is worng

Comment: @Ed_ I agree with ishfaq why would you make staff_id to act as a primary key as well as foreign key ?

Comment: Sir if you are in staff table then obviously you want some primary key then you can use staff_id as a primary key or else but your primary key can only act as a foregn key of another table not the same table